# jenkins: saving parameters of parameterized build for reuse

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, parameterized

I have a parametrized Jenkins task. After the task execution I can see the parameters used for the execution.

I want to reuse parameters of any previous build of the task for following launches.

Brief googling did not help me.

Could you please advise me some solutions for my task?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [**Rebuild Plugin**](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Rebuild+Plugin) -
It allows you to rerun any previous run of a job,
with the same parameters that were used in that run.
You can even change some of the parameters, if needed.

Comment: The only thing I feel is lacking in that approach is that it is not immediately obvious which parameters were used for a build. There should be a list of all used parameters or on each build it should be clearly stated what the parameters were.

Comment: Those values are listed in place when you choose a specific run for re-run. It is true those values are not listed elsewhere. For that you may wish to TAG those runs with **[Groovy Postbuild Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Groovy+Postbuild+Plugin)**.

Answer (score 2):

You could do the following:

1. Save the parameters to a file in properties file format (e.g. using some of the script execution builders)
2. Save this file to a known location within the job
3. Use the Parameterized Trigger Plugin to reuse the parameters